# Почему RecycleView прокручивается после обновления данных?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Для отображения данных в списке использую `Paging Library`. Все отображается хорошо. Прокручиваю `RecycleView` в самый низ. Далее по нажатию на кнопку нужно обновить данные, вызываю у `PositionalDataSource` `invalidate`(). Данные заново загружаются. Вопрос, почему список прокручивается после этого, даже если данные не изменились? Мне нужно просто обновить данные.

Главный код:

```
private fun initViews() {
    val messagesAdapter = TestMessagesAdapter(MessageDiffUtilCallback())
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    factory = MessagesDataSourceFactory()

    recycleView.apply {
        this.layoutManager = layoutManager
        adapter = messagesAdapter
        setHasFixedSize(true)
    }

    val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
        .setPageSize(10)
        .setInitialLoadSizeHint(30)
        .build()
    val pagedListLiveData = LivePagedListBuilder(factory, config)
        .setFetchExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
        .build()

    pagedListLiveData.observe(this, Observer<PagedList<MessageTestModel>?> { pagedList ->
        Log.e(CHAT_TAG, "ChatDetailsFragment submit PagedList")
        messagesAdapter.submitList(pagedList)
    })

    fab.setOnClickListener {
        showToast()
        factory.dataSource?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

`MessagesDataSource`:

```
/**
 * messages всегда передается один и тот же
 */
internal class MessagesDataSource(private val messages: ArrayList<MessageTestModel>) : PositionalDataSource<MessageTestModel>() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "chat_tag"
    }

    init {
        Log.e(TAG, "MessagesDataSource init()")
    }

    override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams, callback: LoadInitialCallback<MessageTestModel>) {
        Log.e(TAG,"MessagesDataSource loadInitData()")
        callback.onResult(messages.subList(0, 10), 0)
    }

    override fun loadRange(params: LoadRangeParams, callback: LoadRangeCallback<MessageTestModel>) {
        Log.e(TAG,"MessagesDataSource loadAfter()")
        val startPosition = params.startPosition
        val endPosition = startPosition + params.loadSize
        if(endPosition <= messages.size) {
            callback.onResult(messages.subList(startPosition, endPosition))
        } else {
            callback.onResult(ArrayList())
        }
    }
}
```

Очень простая реализация на [Github](https://github.com/iamtihonov/TestListBug)

Видео на котором воспроизводится ошибка: https://youtu.be/wkxbrajk8mE

**UPDATE**

Ошибка повторяется при любом верхнем элементе `RecycleView`

Так же нашел похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203591/positionaldatasource-and-recyclerview-why-scroll-after-invalidate). Ещё связанный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55110670/android-paging-library-updating-the-data-on-the-current-page).

Comment: может проблема в xml вашей активности, recyclerview у вас math_parent? его может просто таскать по активности и все)

Comment: @Andrew да math_parent

Comment: а в разметке у вас `tools:itemCount="5"` зачем стоит?

Comment: @Andrew это одно из свойств, что бы можно было смотреть превью списка. В данном случае его можно убрать и нечего не поменяется.

Comment: а он перемещается и остается на своем новом положении или обратно возвращается?

Comment: @Andrew перемещается и остается на своем новом положении

Comment: а вы не пробовали как-то изменить разметку для решения данной проблемы? мне просто кажется что проблема где-то в ней, а не в том как вы данные грузите

Comment: @Andrew может быть, просто разметка помоему и так почти примитивная

Comment: Список view-контейнера или скролл? Было бы неплохо, если бы вы добавили скриншот

Comment: @McDaggen не понял. Используется RecycleView. Скриншот добавил.

Comment: @iamtihonov Скриншот перемещенного вниз списка имел в виду

Comment: @McDaggen Поправил

Comment: так у вас список как виджет сползает или сползает в понятии скроллится до самого низа?

Comment: @Andrew имеется ввиду скролится

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял то что у вас происходит и то что вы в комментариях рассказали, то вам нужно просто после обновления программно проскроллится до верхнего уровня списка. Делается это все так:

```
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Либо через `LinearLayoutManager`:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView
                    .getLayoutManager();
layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
```

оба варианта рабочие, но вообще в сети советуют использовать через `LinearLayoutManager`.

### UPDATE

Чтобы проскроллится до определенной позиции нужно сделать так:

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2, 20);
```

ну а запоминать уже можно двумя вариантами - либо сетить переменную в классе, либо сохранять в SharedPreference.

### UPDATE 2.0

Попробуйте в разметке которая включает в себя ваш список добавить строку:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

У меня была такая же почти проблема, может [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1076164/nestedscrollview-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-android/1076169#1076169) решение вам тоже поможет.

Comment: Скорее немного не так, когда пользователь обновляет данные, запоминать текущую позицию RecycleView и после после обновления восстанавливать, но это скорее всего получится костыль. Если к примеру прокручиваешь только до 10-го элемента и обновляешь, то такого бага нет.

Comment: @iamtihonov, обновил ответ с скроллом до определенной позиции. Мне честно говоря не видно что у вас там происходит)) Поэтому можно сделать так и расценивать это как костыль или как решение проблемы :)

Comment: В любом случае спасибо. Если что, видео ошибки https://youtu.be/wkxbrajk8mE. PS все таки в любом случае RecycleView прокручивается после обновления, хотя раньше не всегда наблюдал.

Comment: Прокручиваю список вниз(верхняя 31-я view), далее обновляю список, recycleView прокручивается вверх, вызываю после scrollToPositionWithOffset(31, 0) - что ни к чему не приводит, видимо из-за того что adapter не знает общее количество элементов. Если все то же самое выполнить, когда верхний к примеру 10-й, то все гуд.

Comment: адаптер должен знать общее кол-во, там функция есть для этого

Comment: Как вы знаете PositionalDataSource подгружает данные для списка по мере надобности, и предназначен для работы в том числе с сетью. То есть сначала может загрузится 20 элементов, через минуту пользователь прокрутил загрузил ещё 10 (но минуту назад их могло быть меньше) и реализация getItemCount в PagedListAdapter не обязательная и данные продолжают загружатся до тех пор пока будут поступать. Но я решил попробовать в адаптере вернуть 40 и это привело к ошибке IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 31, Size: 20. В реальном приложении думаю так лучше не делать.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в либе самой. Как вариант, предлагаю в слушателе `floating button'a` в ручную скроллить к первой позиции ресайкла:

```
recycleView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
```

Comment: Да похоже что в библиотеке. Единственное если скролить к первой, то позиция изменится. А мне нужно просто перезагрузить данные и что бы после обновления отображались те же view что и до обновления. (если нужно обновленные)