# NestedScrollView самостоятельно скроллится android

Tags: android, recyclerview, nested-scrollview

Есть такая разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".pollsModule.PollsScr">


    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/intro_text_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/intro_text_body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/intro_text_header"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_screen_btn"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_below="@id/divider">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/question_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="18sp"
                app:autoSizeMinTextSize="14sp"
                app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/user_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/question_text"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/questionImg"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="QuestionImg"
                android:visibility="gone" />


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/answerOptions"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/user_input"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/question_buttons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/answerOptions"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:weightSum="20">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/prev_question"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:text="@string/previous_question_polls" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/next_question"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:background="@drawable/main_screen_btn"
                    android:text="@string/next_question_polls"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

и там есть такой список:

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/answerOptions"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/user_input"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

В этом списке при определенных условиях может быть такая разметка у элемента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/answerOptions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/question_text"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Если проще говоря, то будет несколько списков внутри одного списка:

```
NestedScrollView
- RecyclerView_1
-- LinearLayout
--- RecyclerView_2
```

Не уверен что правильно изобразил, но я постарался изобразить наглядно)) Суть проблемы: например в списке `RecyclerView_1` 3 элемента а в каждом из 3 списков `RecyclerView_2` есть по 6 элементов. Если мы нажимаем например на один из элементов `RecyclerView_2`, который находится на позиции 2 в `RecyclerView_1` то или мой `NestedScrollView` или `RecyclerView_1` скроллится к самому верху. Не могу понять в чем может быть проблема. Думал сделать smoothScrollTo но не помогло.

Comment: А разве использование `RecylerView` в `NestedScrollView` не приводит к утечкам памяти? Даже при малом количестве элементов списка на старых устройствах приложение тормозило по полной программе, особенно когда элементы сложные.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, вроде эмулятор без фризов работал, на реальных устройствах не пробовал еще. Это считается сложный элемент? Просто второй вариант - это динамическое создание такой разметки и других вариантов у меня нету

Comment: В зависимости от того, сколько у вас там элементов в списке. Возможно проблем не будет. Просто учтите, что `RecylerView` обернутый в `NestedScrollView` заставляет первый вывести все элементы в память, минуя кэширование. Посмотрите в профилировании использование ОЗУ на устройстве. Если для вас это не критично, то конечно такая реализация имеет место быть.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, это единственное что пришло мне на ум по поводу реализации))) другие варианты сложнее будет сделать и выхлоп не очень большой будет. в целом спасибо за полезные советы, нужно будет проверить :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неожиданно нашел вроде решение, когда правильно сформулировал запрос в гугл)) Нужно добавить в `RelativeLayout` который находится внутри `NestedScrollView` такую строку:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34419859/nestedscrollview-scroll-down-itself-when-content-is-fills) где нашел это решение.